# C++ Variadic Template to Evaluate Pointer to Member

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I would like to create a variadic template that evaluates nested pointer to members.  I have tried the following:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename... V>
auto getField(T &input, U (T::*field), V... args)
    -> decltype(getField(input.*field, &args...))
{
    getField(input.*field, &args...);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
U getField(T &input, U (T::*field))
{
    return input.*field;
}

struct inner {
    int val;
};

struct outer {
    inner in;
};

void main() {
    outer p{{5}};
    cout << getField(p, &outer::in, &inner::val) << endl;
}
```

When I compile the above in VS, I get the following error messages:

> error C2672: 'getField': no matching overloaded function found
>   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type getField(T &, U T::* ,V...)'
>   note: With the following template arguments:
>   note: 'T=outer'
>   note: 'U=outer::inner'
>   note: 'V={int outer::inner::* }'

How can I fix the above variadic template to compile, and return `p.in.val`?  Note that my compiler doesn't support auto template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of methods and fix "typos":

```
template<typename T, typename U>
U getField(T &input, U (T::*field))
{
    return input.*field;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... V>
auto getField(T &input, U (T::*field), V... args)
    -> decltype(getField(input.*field, args...))
{
    return getField(input.*field, args...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b9a0ce00c939aea)

Comment: For anyone else who arrived here, the differences are 1) the removal of the ampersand before `args...`, and the addition of the word "return" on the variadic version of the template.  The order of declaration appears to be inconsequential.